# Pandas multiindex: print all of first index if in second index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to query and dataframe and output **all** the items in the first index if it is contained in the second index. 
A simplified version to describe what I am trying to achieve is:

```
data = {'colour': ['red','purple','green','purple','blue','red'], 'item': ['hat','scarf','belt','belt','hat','scarf'], 'material': ['felt','wool','leather','wool','plastic','wool']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
grpd_df = df.groupby(df['item']).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
grpd_df

         colour  item material
item

belt   0 green   belt  leather 
       1 purple  belt  wool 

hat    0 red     hat   felt 
       1 blue    hat   plastic 

scarf  0 purple  scarf wool 
       1 red     scarf wool
```

I would like to obtain all the rows that are in an item that have an  item that is red in colour:

```
hat    0 red     hat   felt 
       1 blue    hat   plastic 

scarf  0 purple  scarf wool 
       1 red     scarf wool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with 2 Series by compared column `color` with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) for at least one `True` per group:

```
df = grpd_df[grpd_df['colour'].eq('red').groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
print (df)
         colour   item material
item                           
hat   0     red    hat     felt
      1    blue    hat  plastic
scarf 0  purple  scarf     wool
      1     red  scarf     wool
```

**Detail**:

```
print (grpd_df['colour'].eq('red').groupby(level=0).transform('any'))
item    
belt   0    False
       1    False
hat    0     True
       1     True
scarf  0     True
       1     True
Name: colour, dtype: bool
```

Slowier alternative with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = grpd_df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: x['colour'].eq('red').any())
```

If want working with original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df[df['colour'].eq('red').groupby(df['item']).transform('any')]
print (df)
   colour   item material
0     red    hat     felt
1  purple  scarf     wool
4    blue    hat  plastic
5     red  scarf     wool
```

EDIT:

If want working with `MultiIndex`:

```
data = {'colour': ['red','purple','green','purple','blue','red'], 'item': ['hat','scarf','belt','belt','hat','scarf'], 'material': ['felt','wool','leather','wool','plastic','wool']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data).set_index(['colour','item'])

print (df)    
             material
colour item          
red    hat       felt
purple scarf     wool
green  belt   leather
purple belt      wool
blue   hat    plastic
red    scarf     wool

df = df[pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values('colour') == 'red', index=df.index).groupby(level=1).transform('any')]
```

Second `filter` solution:

```
df = df.groupby(level=1).filter(lambda x: (x.index.get_level_values('colour') == 'red').any())
```

---

```
print (df)

             material
colour item          
red    hat       felt
purple scarf     wool
blue   hat    plastic
red    scarf     wool
```

Comment: Thats works great. I need to understand how that works. Also how would we output the list of items it is grouped by, i.e. hat scarf, a  `df.index.levels` outputs all the items and we'd only like the  grouped items